# AVPlayer Custrom Scrubbing

Tags: video, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using `AVPlayer` for my tvOS project. Its size is smaller than fullscreen, so its controls are hidden. This is limitation of using `AVPlayer`.

But, I must show the video controls to user, so that user can do play, pause, fast forward, backward, scrubbing etc.

Anyone knows about any third party library or framework or have implemented it before? Please share. I searched a lot but couldn't find any help on internet.

Thanks.

Comment: you could add custom controls over the view i believe ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Apple discourages interaction with Video when you are displaying it in non fullscreen mode. The idea is if the viewer is to be fully engaged in the video, then the video needs to be shown in full screen mode, especially on a TV sized device. Hence AVPlayerViewController is provided which has all default controls as well as Metadata displays/Content Proposals but is available only in full screen mode. Mimicking this behavior in non full screen mode is probably a lot of work and I am unaware of any libraries out there that will provide you with a custom slider that will be help with playback. I highly encourage you to show video in full screen and use the default controls.